# Need help in identifying TYPE of document ingested by Elasticsearch (through Logstash)

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I used Logstash to ingest csv files from https://www.kaggle.com/wcukierski/the-simpsons-by-the-data and saved  it to Elasticsearch. For starters, I ingested `simpsons_characters.csv` using the following conf:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/xyz/Downloads/the-simpsons-by-the-data/simpsons_characters.csv"
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns   => ["id", "name", "normalized_name", "gender"]
    separator => ","
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts   => "localhost"
    action  => "index"
    index   => "simpsons"
  }
}
```

However, when I query like so: `http://localhost:9200/simpsons/name/Lou`
where
`simpsons = index`
`name = type` (I think ... not sure)

I get the following response back:

```
{
   "_index": "simpsons",
   "_type": "name",
   "_id": "Lou",
   "found": false
}
```

So, the question is, why am I not getting the correct response. Further, when you do bulk ingestion through csv, what is the `type` of the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The default `type` in Logstash Elasticsearch output is `logs`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_type). So, no matter how you define your IDs (either take it from the csv - `document_id => "%{id}"` or let ES define its own), you can get those documents as `http://localhost:9200/simpsons/logs/THE_ID`.

If you don't know the id and want to simply check if something is there: `http://localhost:9200/simpsons/logs/_search?pretty`.

If you want to see what is the mapping of your index, for example to find out the `_type` of the index: `http://localhost:9200/simpsons/_mapping?pretty`.

To change the default `_type`:

```
  elasticsearch {
    hosts   => "localhost"
    action  => "index"
    index   => "simpsons"
    document_type => "characters"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
```

Comment: So, I tried, and it works. But, then how do I modify the conf file, such that, instead of `logs` it is `characters`? I guess how do you set the `document_type` so that it doesn't default to `logs`? Thanks!

Comment: You can specify the type like `document_type => "characters"`.

Comment: Yep :) .. I did just that and it worked! Thanks! Marked your answer as the preferred answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here you haven't specified `id field`  in your logstash output. In this case elasticsearch would asign a **random id** to your documents and you are searching for a document with `id=Lou`.
Adding `document_id => "%{id}"` would solve your problem.

```
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts   => "localhost"
    action  => "index"
    index   => "simpsons"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but still getting the same response.
`http://localhost:9200/simpsons/id/1868` returns:
    {
       "_index": "simpsons",
       "_type": "id",
       "_id": "1868",
       "found": false
    }